# Get 401: Invalid Token After install okta-spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, okta

Hi I am now using Angluar + Spring Boot to build a web, I am using okta Single-Page App to do authentication. On my frontend, I can login and redirect back, I also add `Authorization: Bearer {Token}` in the headers when I call backend api.

So the problem is when I installed okta-spring-boot-starter(1.4.0), and I will get the error:

```
 Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Invalid token", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"
```

I was thinking this might because I didn't setup okta configuration.
Then I add the okta properties in application.yml file:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "dev"
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"

okta.oauth2:
  client-id: 0oaebbeiaBCbFFtDU4x6
  issuer: https://dev-574831.okta.com
  audience: https://dev-574831.okta.com
```

and use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter by refering to: https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring/blob/master/resource-server/src/main/java/com/okta/spring/example/ResourceServerExampleApplication.java

```
import com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OktaOAuth2WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/userinfo").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

        http.cors();

        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);

    }
}
```

Still I am getting the same error.

So do I miss something?? or can okta  configuration cannot be recognized by my project?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    client-id: 0oaebbeiaBCbFFtDU4x6
    issuer: https://dev-574831.okta.com/oauth2/default
```

Comment: Actually I tried this before. but got a different error  saying"Signed JWT Rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found". Then I used``` https://dev-574831.okta.com```

Comment: One thing is should I use "Web APP" not "Single Page App"??

Comment: The problem resolved change both frontend(angular) and backend(spring boot) issuer to https://dev-574831.okta.com/oauth2/default. So the thing here is, when I was using https://dev-574831.okta.com as issuer, I get token from "Org Authorization Server" not "Default Authorization Server"